# Support GPOS kerning table by HarfBuzz

Tags: freetype, kerning, harfbuzz

How can HarfBuzz support GPOS kerning? In my task I use the font Myriad.otf. I try to get kerning information through the function `hb_font_get_glyph_kerning_for_direction(....)`. For TTF fonts it works because it uses TrueType `kern` tables, but for Myriad.otf it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you planning for applying that kernings manually? If so, that is not the way harfbuzz intended to be used as harfbuzz provides a simple API that provides eventual result from inputs (hb_shape) and if that is not working, it is a harfbuzz or that font bug. If you however really need to extract GPOS kerning, you can consider reading its related tables (hb_face_reference_table) or check how harfbuzz is reading it for its internal use.